How to automate Azure ServiceBus failover between 2 instances using azure devops pipelines?
We have 2 Azure Servicebus instances (one in region 1 and other in region2) with failover enabled (between region 1 & region 2 instances). As of now we are doing the failover manually.
Looking for a automation on below using azure devops yaml pipelines, where, I need to control each task with manual decision to trigger in a flow.
For example, consider a scenario, where need to do failover from SB-A (region1) to SB-B (region 2)

check the serviceBus regions are already paired or not (SB-A & SB-B).

If not paired, pair the 2 instances using the given alias (SB-PAIR-AB) already set.(in some cases, region 1 to region 2 and other cases, region 2 to region1)

If above verified, enable the failover between 2 regions instances. verify that which region is instance is now active(in this scenario, failover happened from SB-A to SB-B, So SB-A is passive & SB-B is active now) .

After successful verification, another manual determination task to delete all the queues from the passive instance(here in the scenario, SB-A)
Note:- it is noticed that, we can't delete the Queues from SB instances, when they are paired. So we may need to break the pairing for this and Once the Queues are deleted from the Passive instance(SB-A),

Re- initiate the pairing again.



Same way for failover between SB-B to SB-A scenario

We used below AZ commands to achieve this, but couldn't achieve the conditions and flow as mentioned above.
For enabling the pairing
A->B

az servicebus georecovery-alias set --alias SB-PAIR-AB --resource-group  SB-A-rg --namespace-name SB-A --partner-namespace /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/SB-B-rg/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/SB-B'

B->A
az servicebus georecovery-alias set --alias SB-PAIR-AB --resource-group SB-B-rg --namespace-name SB-B --partner-namespace /subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/SB-A-rg/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/SB-A

Failover
A->B
az servicebus georecovery-alias fail-over --alias SB-PAIR-AB  --namespace-name SB-B --is-safe-failover y --resource-group SB-B-rg --subscription B-subscription

B->A
az servicebus georecovery-alias fail-over --alias SB-PAIR-AB --namespace-name SB-A --is-safe-failover y --resource-group SB-A-rg  --subscriptions A-Subscription

Queue Deletion
A->B
az servicebus queue delete --name <queue-names> --namespace-name SB-A  --resource-group SB-A-rg --subscription A-Subscription53

B->A
az servicebus queue delete --name <queue-names> --namespace-name SB-B  --resource-group SB-B-rg --subscription B-subscription


What is the exact error you are facing here? @Vowneee

Even though I have working commands, couldn't achieve the  scenarios and conditions which i mentioned above

I am able to perform the above operations with CLI in my environment and was working as expected. @Vowneee

"Couldn't achieve" means the queue is not getting deleted? @Vowneee

Didnt get a way to check whether the pairing is enabled or not from source to dest. If not need to pair it on conditional basis.

Also Since the failover from source to dest is breaking the pairing after the failover, we cant pair the 2 instances, untill we remove the ques from the passive instance. is it the normal behavior of failover ?.. If yes, can we dynamicaly list the queues in passive instance afyter the failover and delete them ? once deleted re-pair the 2 instances bac ?

Yes, the mechanism is like that. The secondary namespace becomes a standalone namespace after a failover. Before reinitiating the pairing, no queues or message transfer or topics should be existed. @Vowneee

I really do not like the ServiceBus Geo Features as it does not sync Data, etc. Normally I go into an active, active scenario, where both ServiceBus Namespaces will receive the same message and subscriber will deque them in both.

Ya it has few limitations. So what is the requirement you need now? @JulianHüppauff

I was mostly commenting to give a different option to do geo-redundancy. Otherwise I fully agree with @Jahnavi. You need to completely dismantle the previous service bus. Delete all messages, topics/queues, etc.

Any kind of automation we can look for above workflows ?

Will check if anything is possible with ARM and update you. @Vowneee

i identified the above given CLI commands as a option for achieving the tasks, but may be require more conditions on the script to achieve what we are looking for

I tried all the possible ways actually. @Vowneee

So couldn't achieve what we are trying for ?

Working on it still. @Vowneee

Are you still looking for an approach? @Vowneee

Yes...I couldn't achieve this yet
